# Is it possible to install CiviCRM offline using WAMP?

Tags: installation, evaluating-civicrm

My company is interested at offline CRM.

I would like to ask.
Can CiviCRM be installed on WAMP server?

Is it easy to customize fields by the needs of company without to be proficient in Programming/Development.

For example my company just wants a database to store their clients/potential clients and each client will have 50 fields of information (name,surname,address etc)

Is this doable with CiviCRM?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

So no problem installing it on a WAMP, especially if you "only" want it as an "internal address book".

You have quite a lot of fields by default, and if you need more, you can create custom ones directly from the UI, no need to develop anything for your requirement it seems.

But the easiest is that you try, either on your own install or check our demo sites at http://demo.civicrm.org

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can download a ready-made CiviCRM server in the form of a VirtualMachine, such as: https://bitnami.com/stack/civicrm/virtual-machine
which is a VMWare VM.

This will run your CiviCRM locally in a separate virtual machine in your server.

Customizing fields in CiviCRM does not require any programming abilities, yet it takes some getting used to. You will find lots of useful information in this online book: http://book.civicrm.org/user/

Good luck!